# a join or other method to retrieve when one query is null and other have result

Tags: mysql, count, sum, left-join, right-join

I have this sql query which is combining of two query,for a specific user in a unique matter (named title) first return the count and sum of scores where they are negative and second return sum and count of positive scores:

```
 SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT title,
        count(*) cnt_neg,
        sum(score) sum_neg
    FROM scores_ofexpert
    WHERE user_id = "30"
        AND title = "137"
        AND score < 0
    GROUP BY title
    ) neg,
    (
        SELECT count(*) cnt_pos,
            sum(score) sum_pos
        FROM scores_ofexpert
        WHERE user_id = "30"
            AND title = "137"
            AND score >= 0
        GROUP BY title
        ) pos
```

the problem is this: when both return values it work good, but when one return null, both shows null either if i run one it work true. for example if a person with id of 30 have 2 positive score in title1 and no negative score on title1 the query return null for neg_count and neg_sum and pos_sum and pos_count. but if i run only the part which work on positive it work true...

I tried the right join: it work only when second query has result and tried left join and it return value only when first have result. any better way to do this?

Comment: thanks @Anant Dbhi, now it is more readable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer. It worked well for me:

```
    SELECT
     SUM(CASE WHEN s.score < 0 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) n_sum,COUNT(CASE WHEN s.score < 0 THEN s.score END) n_count,
     SUM(CASE WHEN s.score >= 0 THEN s.score ELSE 0 END) p_sum,COUNT(CASE WHEN s.score >= 0 THEN s.score END)  p_count,
     SUM(s.score) `sum`
     FROM scores_ofexpert s
         WHERE s.user_id = '30' and title='135'
    GROUP BY title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RIGHT JOIN (I suspect mysql 5 or greater only, otherwise use left join and swap the sub-queries around). RIGHT JOIN insists on an ON clause but you can use a dummy IE:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT title,
        count(*) cnt_neg,
        sum(score) sum_neg
    FROM scores_ofexpert
    WHERE user_id = "30"
        AND title = "137"
        AND score < 0
    GROUP BY title
    ) neg
RIGHT JOIN
    (
        SELECT count(*) cnt_pos,
            sum(score) sum_pos
        FROM scores_ofexpert
        WHERE user_id = "30"
            AND title = "137"
            AND score >= 0
        GROUP BY title
        ) pos
ON 1=1
```

Comment: thanks @Giles it works if the second have result, but doesn't work if the first is empty. can we have a better solution?

Comment: Well, you can change to left join, but then it won`t work if it is the other way round. What you want is a full outer join (returns all rows from both tables), but mysql does not support this. Your solution below is a much better approach :)

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. [The](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) documentation says:

> INNER JOIN and , (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of
>   a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the
>   specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is
>   joined to each and every row in the second table).

So the first table with 0 rows matches 0 rows in second table and you get no results.
You may have to use a different join condition as required.